# How to override spring-boot's configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jetty

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-web` with `spring-boot-starter-jetty` and I would like to be able to change Jetty's config by injecting my own xml bean. I cannot figure out how to override the configuration in spring-boot-starter-jetty.

Here's a part of my `pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here's how the application starts

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
}
```

I create a bean in a file named `jetty.xml` to override the port for Jetty

```
<bean id="connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <constructor-arg ref="server"/>
        <property name="port" value="8789"/>
</bean>
```

Then I thought by importing this resource, it would override the port in spring-boot

```
@Configuration  
@ImportResource( { "classpath*:jetty.xml" } )  
public class ConfigJetty { }
```

but the port stays at 8080

How can we achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you read [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-the-http-port)? As it is in there quite clearly.

Comment: If you are asking how to change the port on which the spring boot app listens, then you need to set server.port in application.properties, e.g., server.port=8081

Comment: Yes sir. I read it. Maybe I'm confused with this part http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-configuration-classes.html#using-boot-importing-xml-configuration

Comment: @Andonaeus It's not only for the port. I would like to be able to override Jetty's configuration with a bean. If it's possible

Comment: Refer also to whole list of possible properties for embedded containers http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties in section WEB PROPERTIES

Comment: So there's no way I can override the properties by injecting my own bean?

Comment: Spring Boot also has a chapter about programmatic customization: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-programmatic-embedded-container-customization

Comment: @dunni the only problem with that is that it's through the code not a xml file

Comment: And why is that a problem?

Comment: @dunni It's harder to change. I would have to compile the project if I wanna change some configurations. We don't have that problem with xml

Comment: You can use properties in your Java configuration (if there aren't properties provided already by Spring, create/use your own). Or completely disable the Jetty auto configuration and provide your own configuration.

Comment: Yeah sadly I think I'm gonna have to disable the Jetty auto configuration

Comment: And why wouldn't you have to repackage i.e. rebuild your application with XML? It is still just configuration although in Java and not XML. The xml is part of the same war/jar and that still needs to be rebuild. I also wonder what you are trying to do that isn't possible with the different properties. Basically the only thing you would need to do is create an `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` implementation which modifies what you want. Instead of working around the framework I strongly suggest working WITH the framework.

Comment: @M.Deinum No, you don't need to rebuild the jar file if you modify the xml. It's a separate file that you load at run-time.

Comment: That depends on the location of the xml file, however I think it is quite dangerous to have such a critical thing in an external file. However you still haven't answered the question on what you want to configure what isn't available through properties.

Comment: @M.Deinum it was only for consistency. The other projects has xml beans. I ended up using the properties.

Comment: Maybe this article could help. http://jdpgrailsdev.github.io/blog/2014/10/07/spring_boot_jetty_thread_pool.html See the `JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory`

Answer (score 0):

'In a standalone application the main HTTP port defaults to 8080, but can be set with server.port (e.g. in application.properties or as a System property). '

Comment: It's not only for the port. I would like to be able to override Jetty's configuration with a bean. If it's possible